# Discord.py Reaction bot that gives a role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I make a bot that would give people roles when they reacted to a specific thing? So far I have this but it does not work

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel('513546504481406979')
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="testrole")
    message = await bot.send_message(channel, "React to me!")
    while True:
        reaction = await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=message)
        await bot.add_roles(reaction.message.author, role)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`wait_for_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_reaction) returns a `(reaction, user)` tuple.  You only need the `user` portion to assign the role:

```
reaction, reactor = await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=message)
await bot.add_roles(reactor, role)
```

Comment: I keep getting the error

Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "python", line 11, in on_ready
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Comment: Do you have some global variable `user` that you're using to get the role? (You could just use the role id). You can replace the name `user` in my code with any other name

Comment: I do not have a global user variable user.server.roles is not working for some reason

Comment: The reason is because `user` isn't defined.  Use `channel.server.roles` instead