# How to create "react to role" embed message with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to set up an embedded message that has emojis reacted on it, where when a user clicks on a certain emoji, it gives them a role. I've been digging to find help everywhere...

I've got the embedded message part, but just don't know how to add the emoji reactions to the embed or have it set to grant a user the role upon click of the emoji.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
      #ignore this portion
 if message.author == client.user:
  return
 elif message.content.startswith("~ping"):
  await client.send_message(message.channe,"Pong!")
      #read below this now
 elif message.content.startswith("~embed"):
  emb = (discord.Embed(title="role Update", description="Use the emotes to role", colour=0x3DF270))
  await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=emb)

 elif message.content.startswith("~embedroles"):
  channel = bot.get_channel('532629344774914069')
  role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="test")
  while True:
   reaction = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji='\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}', message=message)
   await bot.add_roles(reaction.message.author, role)
```

I hope this makes sense. Here is an example of what I'm referring to...https://imgur.com/2QYCSAi

Comment: Related: [Discord.py Reaction bot that gives a role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53357677/6779307)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remember that you're limited to 20 reactions per message.

To add a reaction, you have to pass through its Unicode version, or the `discord.Emoji` object. As said in the [faq](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message), you need to use the [`Client.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_reaction), which takes the message and the emoji to react with as arguments.

To get the `discord.Message` object, simply assign the sent message to a variable: `reacted_message = await client.send_message(channel, embed=embed)`.

You may iterate on a tuple  containing the reactions to add (with a simple for loop) to make the bot react to the message.

Instead of using the [`Client.wait_for_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_reaction) method, which is useful when you can only react in a limited time, I suggest you use the [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) event, which will feedback a `discord.Reaction` and the `discord.User` whom reacted.

In this event, you need to compare the message which got a reaction, accessible with `discord.Reaction.message` with the message you are watching. That's why the message we kept in a variable before should be saved somewhere accessible, such as an attribute of your bot (let's say `self.watched_messages`), so you can first check if the message is a "watched one". Instead of using the message object directly, I suggest you use its ID as a key in a dict (`self.watched_messages`), the value being another dict: the 'role-giving' reactions (their Unicode value, or ID if customs) and the roleID to give.

If the reacted message ID is in the dict, and if the emoji is in the list indexed by the messageID in the key, then you use [`Client.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles) to add the role to the Member.

As you only get the `discord.User` which reacted, you need to get the right `discord.Member` to add a role to. You may pass by the `discord.Message.server`.

Similarly (keeping the same nested dicts), use the [`on_reaction_remove`](http://discordhttps://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles) event to remove the role, with [`Client.remove_roles`](http://discordhttps://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles).

this is a pseudo-code for what I had in mind

```py
    # template of the nested dict:
    watched_messages = {
        messageID: {
            regularEmojiName: roleID,
            customEmojiID: roleID
        }
    }

    async def manage_reaction(self, reaction, user, added: bool):
        if not reaction.message.id in self.watched_messages:
            return

        messageID = reaction.message.id
        mapping = self.watched_messages[messageID]
        if not reaction.emoji in mapping:
            # reaction.emoji is str if normal emoji or ID if custom, but we use both as keys in mapping
            return

        member = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.server.members, id=user.id)
        role = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.server.roles, id=mapping[reaction.emoji])

        if added:
            await client.add_roles(member, role)
        else:
            await client.remove_roles(member, role)

    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        await self.manage_reactions(reaction, user, True)

    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_remove(self, reaction, user):
        await self.manage_reactions(reaction, user, False)
```

Comment: I really appreciate this - but i'm just lost when I am only given an avenue of "you use these events triggers. Like I can figure out which events to trigger, but I fail at the setup portion of those events. I'm so frustrated with it...

Comment: Man...thanks a ton. I hate to ask more questions but again, I'm just so new to this and I learn by doing and by sheer trial and error. But where will I input the emoji, role, and message ID?The custom emote is "<:blyat:491727892502282241>", the role is "testrole", and the message ID is "532629344774914069". I just seem to be placing them in the wrong place.

Comment: How do you make the user choose the reactions to use?

Comment: I want the bot to add the reactions where then the user just has to select the reaction instead of pulling it from the list

Comment: Yes but when creating a new "role-giving" message. How do you, from Discord, tells the bot the reactions to use?

Comment: I think this should be reaction by reaction, providing both the emoji and the role ID to the bot.

Comment: Like once you sent the message, `!react messageID :emoji: roleID`